# Enable log on Mosquitto which is running as a Windows service on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, logging, server, mosquitto

I want to enable logging on Mosquitto which is running as a Windows service on Windows Server 2016.

I know I have to change the mosquitto.conf file and restart the service, but I don't know how to change the mosquitto.conf correctly.

I have mosquitto installed under C:\Program Files\mosquitto\ and I want to enable the following

```
log_type error
log_type warning
log_type notice
log_type information
connection_messages true
log_timestamp true
```

I want everything to be logged into a single txt-file under the same folder.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `log_dest` option as follows:

```
log_dest file "C:\Program Files\mosquitto\mosquitto.log"
```

Comment: Thanks. But is there something more I have to do as mosquitto won't start as a Windows Service after my modification of mosquitto.conf?

Comment: try running `mosquitto.exe -c /path/to/config` it should give an indication about what is wrong with the config file. If that still doesn't work, edit the question to include you whole config file.

Comment: I get "Error: Unable to open log file "C:\Program Files\mosquitto\log.txt" for writing". I can't see that the log-file is locked by certain permissions though...

Comment: Try a path without any spaces in it and without the quotes

Comment: Yep. For reference, this had to be the following: `log_dest file C:\Progra~1\mosquitto\mosquitto.log`

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly old but as it's the first hit in a Google search I'll add my recent experience.

In `mosquitto.conf` you need the following (adapt for wherever your log is):

```
log_dest file C:\Program Files\mosquitto\var\mosquitto.log
```

Note: no quotes, spaces okay, no need for e.g. "Progra~1".

You'll need to specify the log types (adjust as desired):

```
log_type error
log_type warning
log_type notice
log_type information
```

I'd suggest adding / uncommenting this to make the logs easier to read:

```
log_timestamp true
log_timestamp_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
```

If your service is running as Local System you can skip this step, otherwise you need to explicitly give sufficient - i.e. minimum modify + read + write - permissions to the account your Windows Service is running as, to the folder in which the log will be (hence why mine is in a sub-folder).

Then you need to delete or rename any existing log file, and let Mosquitto create it when starting the service (this is what got me for a while).

Once it's started and the log file is created, it will *only have permissions for the Windows Service account*, so even as an Administrator you won't initially be able to open it.  Go into the Security properties of the file and 1) take ownership with your account, and b) enable inheritance (simplest, but any other method you prefer will do).

Comment: Ah... no quotes... yep, that works :-)

Comment: *take ownership with your account* I'm logged in as admin. It shows `Administrators` as the owner of the log file and I still don't have access.